# How to add a vertical line to a plot?

Tags: plotting

In the plot below I would like to add two vertical lines at $x = \frac{\pi}{15} \pm \frac{1}{20}$.
How can I do that?

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> π/15, z -> 1, q -> π/600}
Plot[{f[x], f[π/15],f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]}, {x, π/15 - .01, π/15 + .01}]
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Are you sure you want +-1/20? This is outside your current plot range.

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25373)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

An easy way to add a vertical line is by using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html).

Here is an example:

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> π/15, z -> 1, q -> π/600}
Quiet[maxy = FindMaxValue[f[x], x]*1.1]
lineStyle = {Thick, Red, Dashed};
line1 = Line[{{π/15 + 1/50, 0}, {π/15 + 1/50, maxy}}];
line2 = Line[{{π/15 - 1/50, 0}, {π/15 - 1/50, maxy}}];
Plot[{f[x], f[π/15], f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]}, {x, π/15 - 1/20, π/15 + 1/20},
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Directive[lineStyle], Directive[lineStyle]},
    Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], line1, line2}]
```

[image: Vertical lines added]

## Caveat

While adding lines as `Epilog` (or `Prolog`) objects works most cases, the method can easily fail when automated, for example by automatically finding the minimum and maximum of the dataset. See the following examples where **the red vertical line is missing** at $x=5$:

```
data1 = Table[0, {10}];
data2 = {1., 1., 1.1*^18, 1., 6., 1.2, 1., 1., 1., 148341.};

Row@{
  ListPlot[data1, Epilog -> {Red, Line@{{5, Min@data1}, {5, Max@data1}}}],
  ListPlot[data2, Epilog -> {Red, Line@{{5, Min@data2}, {5, Max@data2}}}]
  }
```

[image]

In the left case, `Min` and `Max` of data turned out to be the same, thus the vertical line has no height. For the second case, *Mathematica* fails to draw the line due to automatically selected `PlotRange` (selecting `PlotRange -> All` helps). Furthermore, if the plot is part of a dynamical setup, and the vertical plot range is manipulated, the line endpoints must be updated accordingly, requiring extra attention.

## Solution

Though all of these cases can be handled of course, a more convenient and easier option would be to use [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html):

```
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, π/15 - 1/20, π/15 + 1/20},
    GridLines -> {{π/15 + 1/50, π/15 - 1/50}, {f[π/15], f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

And for the extreme datasets:

```
Row@{
  ListPlot[data1, GridLines -> {{{5, Red}}, None}],
  ListPlot[data2, GridLines -> {{{5, Red}}, None}]
  }
```

[image: Example image with vertical grid lines]

Comment: @Istvan thanks for the edit.

Comment: Welcome Ajasja. A certain `data2` & `Epilog` combo pissed me off recently triggering this edit. Sadly, I can't give a sound explanation on why *Mathematica* fails to draw the `Line` in that case. Perhaps someone else has an insight on this.

Comment: In the `Epilog` version, I'd personally use `Scaled[]` instead of futzing around with bounds. Witness for instance `ListPlot[{1., 1., 1.1*^18, 1., 6., 1.2, 1., 1., 1., 148341.}, Epilog -> {Blue, Line[{Scaled[{0, -1}, {5, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {5, 0}]}]}]`.

Comment: @J. M. Yes, I was about to add that (even before István's edit). The problem is that only the y coordinate should be scaled not the x. And `{x, Scaled[y]}` is not valid.

Comment: I'm not scaling the $x$-coordinate in what I'm proposing. Look at the output carefully. Also look up the *two-argument* form of `Scaled[]`.

Comment: @J. M. Aaah, brilliant. Second argument of `Scaled`. Who knew...:) Will edit this in tomorrow.

Comment: "Who knew..." - [I did.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25376) ;)

Comment: You can also use `InfiniteLine`

Answer (score 47):

One way is to use `GridLines`:

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> π/15, z -> 1, q -> π/600}

Plot[f[x], {x, π/15 - .1, π/15 + .1}, 
 GridLines -> {{Pi/15 - 1/20, Pi/15 + 1/20}, {f[Pi/15], f[Pi/15]/Sqrt[2]}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 23):

I assume you mean $x = \frac{\pi}{15} \pm \frac{1}{200}$. Then you can use `Prolog` or `Epilog` with `InfiniteLine`, like this:

```
Plot[
  f[x], 
  {x, π/15 - .01, π/15 + .01},
  Epilog -> {
    (* add vertical lines *)
    InfiniteLine[{π/15 + 1/200, 0}, {0, 1}],
    InfiniteLine[{π/15 - 1/200, 0}, {0, 1}]
  }
]
```

[image: output]

This **does not require you to know the plot range**, nor any of the function values. In addition, you are still free to use `GridLines` for actual grid lines.

In case you don't want to cross the $x$-axis, you can use `HalfLine` instead of `InfiniteLine`, and fix the position of the axis with the `AxesOrigin` option:

```
Plot[
  f[x],
  {x, π/15 - .01, π/15 + .01},
  AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 0},
  Epilog -> {
    (* add vertical lines *)
    HalfLine[{π/15 + 1/200, 0}, {0, 1}],
    HalfLine[{π/15 - 1/200, 0}, {0, 1}]
  }
]
```

[image: output2]

Comment: I use `InfiniteLine` all the time for this sort of thing. Works if you log plot and as you say you don't have to worry about scaling etc.  To minimise typing I would write `InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ {\[Pi]/15 + 1/20, \[Pi]/15 - 1/20}`  Highly recommended approach.

Answer (score 15):

Can use `Show`, but `Epilog` is better.

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> π/15, z -> 1, q -> π/600}
plot = Plot[{f[x], f[π/15], 
    f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]}, {x, π/15 - .01, π/15 + .01}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.26}, Automatic}];

Show[plot, 
 Graphics[{Black, Line[{{Pi/15 + 1/20, 2000}, {Pi/15 + 1/20, 9000}}]}],
 Graphics[{Black, Line[{{Pi/15 - 1/20, 2000}, {Pi/15 - 1/20, 9000}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Why is `Epilog` better?

Comment: @Kvothe With Epilog the plot is self-contained as a simple Graphics object rather than a more complicated Show object which would be less manipulable for further processes.

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility is to use `ParametricPlot` in tandem with `Show`:

```
Show[{
  Plot[{f[x], f[Pi/15], f[Pi/15]/Sqrt[2]}, {x, 0.1, 0.3}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, Axes -> False],

  ParametricPlot[{{Pi/15 + 1/20, u}, {Pi/15 - 1/20, u}}, {u, 0, 9000},
    PlotStyle -> Black]
  }]
```

[image: ParametricPlot]

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `Ticks`:

```
Plot[{f[x], f[π/15], f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]}, {x, π/15 - .06, π/15 + .06},
     Ticks -> {{{π/15 + 1/20, π/15 + 1/20, {0.595, 0}, Directive[Red, Dashed]},
                {π/15 - 1/20, π/15 - 1/20, {0.595, 0}, Directive[Blue, Dashed]}},
                All}, PlotRange -> {{0.12, 0.3}, All}]
```

Comment: Clever manipulation of the `Ticks` specification, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Next possibility is to use `ListPlot`:

```
gp1 = Plot[{({f[x], f[π/15], f[π/15]/Sqrt[2]},{x, π/15 - .05, π/15 + .05}];

ymax = Max[Last /@ Level[Cases[%, _Line, Infinity], {-2}]];

gp2 = ListPlot[{{{π/15 - 1/20, 0}, {π/15 - 1/20,ymax}}, {{π/15 + 1/20, 0}, {π/15 + 1/20, ymax}}},
Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{0.15, 0.26}, All}];
Show[{gp1, gp2}]
```

Comment: You might want to note how I formatted your previous answer, and apply that formatting to this answer...

Comment: You may also find it valuable to register your account.

Comment: You can also use `Overlay[]` instead of `Show[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a vertical line by adding a line with a very large slope like maybe 100 or 1000. If your eyesight is so good that you can see the difference between a high slope and infinity, then increase the slope to a million or a billion.  It is important to use the PlotRange parameter, otherwise the plot will distorted by the high slope of the verticle lines.

```
Plot[{f[x], f[\[Pi]/15], f[\[Pi]/15]/Sqrt[2], 
  1*^6 (x - (\[Pi]/15 - 1/20)), 
  1*^6 (x - (\[Pi]/15 + 1/20))}, {x,Pi/15 - .1, \ 
  [Pi]/15 + .1},PlotRange -> {0, 1000}]
```