# How to insert guide-lines in graphics without specifying range?

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to insert guide lines in Graphics - for example a horizontal line through y=0 coordinate without specifying the range of the line?

Originally I assumed Infinity might do the trick:

```
Graphics[{Point[{0, 1}], Line[{{-Infinity, 0}, {Infinity, 0}}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

But this results in the error message:

```
Coordinate {DirectedInfinity[-1], 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

So Instead of `Infinity`, it's possible to insert such a line using `Epilog` with large magnitude parameters, eg -50 to 50. The reason for Epilog is so that PlotRange->All can be used without having to specify a narrower range (see following example)

However (1) Epilog causes some of the line to be displayed outside the graphics' frame, eg in the following graphic (which shows the interpolated spectrum between the signed & unsigned graph Laplacian), and (2) specifying -50, and 50 (or -500 to 500) is a hack since for some graphs it may not cover the range (for very large graphs or if zooming out to view beyond the D-A to D+A vertical range).

[image]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3561/121

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for the `GridLines` option.  For example,

```
Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 10}, GridLines -> {Automatic, {1/2}}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want other shapes or a diagonal line that is independent of the coordinate range, use scaled coordinates, like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Gray, Line[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]}]}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Scaled coordinates will make sure the line won't go outside the frame if you only use coordinates between 0 and 1.

Comment: I wish I could +2 this.  Great to know about "scaled" coordinates for GridLines.

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs, that should work fine.

Comment: Here's a problem: how would I use Scaled to draw crosshairs through the origin? Recall in the problem above PlotRange->All is critical. How to map the origin {0,0} to Scaled coordinates?

Comment: @alancalvitti use `GridLines` if you want to pass through the origin as per example above.

Comment: Welcome to the 20K club. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard All I want now is an Epic badge :-)

Comment: I want a Populist badge; I suspect you'll achieve your goal first!

Comment: I have a problem which cannot be solved either with `Scaled` coordinates or with `GridLines`: how do you create a half-line that starts at e.g. `{5, 0.8}` and extends to `{Infinity, 0.8}`, where 0.8 should be an absolute coordinate. I could not come up with a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 9):

In the spirit of offering alternatives, here is the following which combines an independently specified set of lines with any plot using `Show`.

**Frame Padding**

Just combining a line in absolute coordinates shows that `Frame` has padded the edge of the plot:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   GridLines -> None];

Show[p, Graphics[Line[{{0, 0.5}, {10, 0.5}}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Scaled Coordinates**

Using scaled coordinates allows the line to span the whole plot area.

```
Show[p, Graphics[Line[{Scaled@{0, 0.5}, Scaled@{10, 0.5}}]]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Many Lines**

Multiple lines can be handled thus:

```
lines = {{{0, 1/3}, {1, 1/3}}, {{0, 2/3}, {1, 2/3}}, {{1/3, 0}, {1/3, 
     1}}, {{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 1}}};

makeGrid[lines_] := Graphics[Line[Scaled /@ #] & /@ lines]

Show[p, makeGrid@lines]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]