# How to add a grid on Plot, ListLinePlot and ListPlot?

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert guide-lines in graphics without specifying range?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/how-to-insert-guide-lines-in-graphics-without-specifying-range)

When we're using `ArrayPlot`, it's possible to draw a grid by doing:

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}, Mesh -> True]
```

But I can't find a way of doing it on `Plot`, `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot`, can you help me?

Comment: Also, many more [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=gridlines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GridLines`? eg

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10, .1}], GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and similarly for

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10, .1}], GridLines -> Automatic]
```