# How to plot multiple horizontal lines?

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert guide-lines in graphics without specifying range?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8646/how-to-insert-guide-lines-in-graphics-without-specifying-range)

How to plot multiple horizontal lines?

For instance, I want to plot 3 horizontal lines: `y=-1`, `y=0` and `y=1`.
Seems to be a pretty simple thing, but I couldn't figure out how; although I've searched all over the documentation center.

Comment: check out `GridLines` with some of the examples of gridlines with specific values.

Comment: @LeiChen Can you add more detail to your question? Do you want a graphic only with lines or do you want the lines in a e.g. plot of a function as grid?

Comment: @halirutan I just want multiple horizontal lines. How to plot Function with grid is well explained by the documentation center. Thanks!

Comment: Drawing lines is also pretty well covered in the manual. What was the problem you faced there?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to draw `Line`s, than you can create your own `Graphics`. I hope the code is self-explanatory

```
Graphics[{
  Line[{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}],
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
  Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks!!  You just solved something I wasn't able to figure out a whole night!

Comment: @LeiChen Then please take some minutes to read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq). Especially, you should understand that we have a voting system here and the -1 infront of your question means in your case: "your question is not explained in detail so that it is not clear what you mean". You can always edit your question and you should learn what up/downvoting and accepting is!

Comment: even that is easier to do with gridLines -- `Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {None, {-1, 0, 1}}]`

Answer (score 1):

The long way round:

```
Plot[
 {
  Evaluate[y = -1],
  Evaluate[y = 0],
  Evaluate[y = 1]
 }, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image: the plot thickens]

Comment: Why not just `Plot[{-1, 0, 1}, ...]`?

Comment: :) I was trying to get as close to the question as possible...