# Adding Lines to Sparklines (plots w/o frames, axes, etc.)

Tags: plotting

I have been working with Sparklines, thanks to some [code found here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/01/06/mathematica-for-web-analytics/). Here is what I am using:

```
sparkline[data_] :=
 DateListPlot[data, {1997}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{{2007, 1, 15}, Red}}, 
    None}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
  ImageSize -> 120]
```

Here is my data:

```
data={{0, 0.00342768669164354`, 0.00503464769633257`, 0, 0.000187`, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0.0415627991238424`, 0.0545451018506565`, 
      0.0395873926886832`, 0.0284671754269643`, 0.0390903566779343`, 
      0.0344695110117644`, 0.0326128167712641`, 0.0380630684019641`, 
      0.0358499768032886`, 0.0241216221583061`, 0.0421644617338612`, 
      0.013010650199335`, 0.0249861212092993`, 0.0052690153372215`}};
```

I have been arranging them in charts, like so:

```
Grid[{{"Topic No.", "Sparkline"}, {"1", sparkline[data[[1]]]}, {"2", 
   sparkline[data[[2]]]}}, Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {None, {LightGray}}]
```

[image]

What I am trying to do, so far unsuccessful, is find options  to put lines within the Sparkline to indicate a specific date. i.e. is there a way that I could add a line for the year '2005' in the example above? The beauty of the Sparkline lies in having no frame or printed axes, but most of the Mathematica commands that come to mind rely on those.

My end goal would be to have something like this (where the line is at 2005, although this is just a mock up):

[image]

Comment: Look into the option `GridLines`.

Comment: @J.M. - me thinks Alpha's Epilog is the better solution, more possibilities.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Epilog` to add lines and other things to your graphs. The simplest solution would be to add it to the sparkline function, like so:

```
sparkline[data_] := 
 DateListPlot[data, {1997}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{{2007, 1, 15}, Red}}, 
    None}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
  ImageSize -> 120, 
  Epilog -> Line[{{{2005, 1, 1}, 0}, {{2005, 1, 1}, 1}}]]
```

Which give you:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12):

Mr Alpha's answer is correct. `Epilog` (or `Prolog`) is the right way to get such annotations onto this or any other kind of graph. One caveat, though: if you are using `Epilog` within the function definition to get some other effect, e.g. [Tufte-style dots for minimum and maximum data points](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0001OR) or whatever it may be, you need to make sure that the function definition you are using can incorporate both the special line you want, and the standard annotations provided in your function.

While perhaps a little complex for this illustration, here is some code I happen to have lying around that does sparkline plots, complete with a range of options.

```
Options[SparklinePlot] = {ShowMinMax -> True, ShowSDBar -> False, 
  LastDotColor -> Red, MinMaxColor -> Hue[0.6], 
  SDBarColor -> {GrayLevel[0.4], Opacity[0.2]}, 
  SparktextStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Gill Sans", FontSize -> 9}, 
  DateStringForm -> {"DayShort", "/", "MonthShort", "/", "YearShort"}};

SparklinePlot[dateddata : {{_List, _?NumericQ} ..}, title_String, 
 opts:OptionsPattern[{SparklinePlot,DateListPlot}]] :=
 With[{data = dateddata[[All, 2]]},
  With[{showmax = OptionValue[ShowMinMax], showsdbar = OptionValue[ShowSDBar ],
    ldcolor = OptionValue[LastDotColor], mmcolor = OptionValue[MinMaxColor],
    sdbcolor = OptionValue[SDBarColor], textstyle = OptionValue[SparktextStyle], 
    epi = OptionValue[Epilog],  datestringform =  OptionValue[DateStringForm ],
    mind = Min[data], maxd = Max[data], sd = StandardDeviation[data], ave = Mean[data]
    }, Grid[{{Graphics[
       DateListPlot[dateddata,Epilog :> {epi}~Join~{ldcolor, AbsolutePointSize[4.5], 
          Point[Last[dateddata]], 
          Sequence @@ If[showmax, {mmcolor, 
             Point[dateddata[[Position[data, mind][[1, 1]]]]], 
             Point[dateddata[[
               Position[data, maxd][[1, 1]]]]]}, {mmcolor}],        
          Sequence @@ If[showsdbar, {Sequence @@ sdbcolor, 
             Rectangle[{First[First[dateddata]], 
               ave - sd}, {First[Last[dateddata]], 
               ave + sd}]}, {mmcolor}]
          }, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]], Joined -> True, Frame -> False, 
        Axes -> False,  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[5/Length[data]], 0.4 sd}, 
        AspectRatio -> 0.2, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[0.75]}, 
        ImageSize -> 150 ], ImagePadding -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0], 
      Graphics[
       Style[Text[ToString[NumberForm[Last[data], 4]]], ldcolor, 
        Sequence @@ textstyle], ImageSize -> 30, AspectRatio -> 1/4], 
      If[showmax, 
       Graphics[
        Style[Text[ToString[NumberForm[mind, 4]]], mmcolor, 
         Sequence @@ textstyle], ImageSize -> 30, AspectRatio -> 1/4],
        Graphics[Text[""], ImageSize -> 0.2]], 
      If[showmax, 
       Graphics[
        Style[Text[ToString[NumberForm[maxd, 4]]], mmcolor, 
         Sequence @@ textstyle], ImageSize -> 30, AspectRatio -> 1/4],
        Graphics[Text[""], ImageSize -> 0.2]], 
      Graphics[
       Style[Text[title], Black, TextAlignment -> Left, 
        Sequence @@ textstyle], 
       ImageSize -> Max[23, StringLength[title]*4.3], 
       AspectRatio -> 1/StringLength[title]]},
     {Graphics[
       Text[Style[DateString[First[First[dateddata]], datestringform],
          Black, TextAlignment -> Left, Sequence @@ textstyle], 
        TextAlignment -> Left], ImageSize -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1/6],
      Graphics[
       Style[Text[DateString[First[Last[dateddata]], datestringform]],
         ldcolor, Sequence @@ textstyle], ImageSize -> 40, 
       AspectRatio -> 1/6],
      If[showmax, 
       Graphics[
        Style[Text[
          DateString[First[dateddata[[Position[data, mind][[1, 1]]]]],
            datestringform]], mmcolor, Sequence @@ textstyle], 
        ImageSize -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1/4], 
       Graphics[Text[""], ImageSize -> 0.2]],
      If[showmax, 
       Graphics[
        Style[Text[
          DateString[First[dateddata[[Position[data, maxd][[1, 1]]]]],
            datestringform]], mmcolor, Sequence @@ textstyle], 
        ImageSize -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1/4], 
       Graphics[Text[""], ImageSize -> 0.2]], 
      Graphics[Text[""], ImageSize -> 0.2]}}, 
    Alignment -> {Join[{Left}, 
       If[showmax, Table[Right, {3}], Table[Right, {1}]]], 
      Join[{Left}, 
       If[showmax, Table[Right, {3}], Table[Right, {1}]], {Left}] }, 
    Spacings -> {0, -0.2}]
   ]]
```

Things to note include

- the use of both the name of this function and `DateListPlot` in the pattern `opts:OptionsPattern[{SparklinePlot,DateListPlot}]` in the function call definition;
- catching of the `OptionValue[Epilog]` in the local constant `epi`, which is then joined to the other things defined to be in the `Epilog`;
- the way the `Epilog` option is constructed *before* the other options passed to  `DateListPlot` are actually passed. This is important so that you don't inadvertently set the `Epilog` option *before* inserting the elements defined in the body of the function definition, as opposed to passed in the function call by the user.

Here is an illustration of the function:

```
testdata = 
  Transpose[{DatePlus[{2000, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 119], 
    FoldList[0.99 #1 + #2 &, 0., RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 119 ]]}];

SparklinePlot[testdata, "Random Series", ShowSDBar -> True, 
 Epilog -> Line[{{{2005}, -11}, {{2005}, 11}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative why not use `GridLines` as per J.Ms comment.

```
sparkline[data_, datemarker_] := DateListPlot[data, {1997},
  AspectRatio -> 0.2,
  Axes -> False,
  Filling -> Bottom,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{{2007, 1, 15}, Red}}, None},
  Frame -> False,
  GridLines -> {{datemarker}, None},
  Joined -> True,
  ImageSize -> 120,
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
```

insert `{2005,1,1}` as the marker date:

```
Grid[{{"Topic No.", "Sparkline"}, {"1", sparkline[data[[1]], {2005, 1, 1}]},
{"2", sparkline[data[[2]],{2005, 1, 1}]}},Frame -> All, Background -> {None, {LightGray}}]
```

[image]

You can insert a `GridLinesStyle` option to style the lines.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:** Using **`Frame`** and **`FrameTicks`:**

```
ClearAll[sparkline2B];
sparkline2B[data_, datespec_, linedates_, linestyles_] := 
DateListPlot[data, datespec,
 Joined -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {Thread[{DateList /@ linedates, "", {.2, .0}, 
  linestyles}, List, {1, -1, 3}], Automatic, Automatic, Automatic},
 Frame -> {True, False, False, False}, FrameStyle -> White,
 Axes -> False, GridLines -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 420]
```

The third argument can be mixed list of elements with `Heads`: `List`, `String`, `DateList`, or `DateString`:

Examples:

```
sparkline2B[data, {1997}, {{2003, 3, 20}}, Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

```
sparkline2B[data, {1997}, {{2003, 3, 20}, "15 Jan, 2007"},Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

```
dates = {"15 Jan, 1999", {2000, 3, 20}, DateString["15 Jan, 2003"],
 DateString[{2004, 5}], DateList[{2006, 3, 20}], DateList["15 Jan, 2007"]};
colors = {Red, Directive[Thick, Green], Directive[Blue, Dashed],
 Directive[Brown, Dashed, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thin, Dotted], Purple};
sparkline2B[data, {1997}, dates2, colors2]
```

[image]

**Method 2:** Yet another alternative is to use a combination of options **`Axes`, `AxesOrigin`, `Ticks`** with  appropriate settings:

```
 ClearAll[sparkline2];
 sparkline2[data_, date_] := 
 DateListPlot[data, {1997}, Joined -> True, Frame -> False, 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, AspectRatio -> 0.2, ImageSize -> 120,   
 Axes -> {False, True}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {DateList[date], Automatic}, 
 AxesStyle -> Red, 
 Ticks -> {{}, {}}, 
 ]
```

Example:

```
 {#, sparkline2[data, #]} & /@ 
 {"15 Jan, 1999", {2000, 3, 20}, 
  DateString["15 Jan, 2003"], 
  DateString[{2004, 5}], 
  DateList[{2006, 3, 20}], 
  DateList["15 Jan, 2007"]} 
  //  Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]