# Adding custom GridLines to the "automatic" ones

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I need to add custom (vertical) grid lines to a plot (to a `DateListPlot`, to be precise). I know there is the option of `GridLines -> {xgrid, ygrid}`. However, this removes the automatic grid lines which I would like to keep.

Is there a simple option to add *additional* grid lines to the automatic ones? Thank you!

---

**Update:** Added a minimal working example.

Take the following `DateListPlot`

```
DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: automatic grid lines]

It automatically includes vertical grid lines for each year in grey, which I would like to keep. But let's say I'd like to add a grid line for Guy Fawkes Day 2007, e.g. because I need to later label the event in the plot. I could write

```
 DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True,
              GridLines -> {{"5 Nov 2007"}, None}]
```

[image: custom grid lines]

but this removes the yearly lines. So I was wondering whether it is possible to *add* the custom grid lines to the automatic ones rather than to overwrite the latter.

Of course, I could manually re-add the annual grid lines, but I hope to avoid this solution because the plots will have different date ranges so I do not always know for which years I'd need to include the lines.

Comment: If you add code for a small working example, more people will likely be inclined to help you.

Comment: I've included an example.

Comment: At worst, one could fall back on `Epilog` and manually add markers for "special" dates (that is, explicitly construct a vertical `Line[]`).

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but then I would need to know the y coordinates of the line (i.e. upper and lower bounds), which depends on the range of the data to be plotted. Else, the line will be taller or shorter than the grid itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure why J.M.'s comment doesn't meet your requirements:

```
DateListPlot[
 RandomReal[1, 20], {2000},
 Joined -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 GridLines -> {Automatic, None},
 Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Magenta],
   Line[
    {Scaled[{0, -1}, {{2010, 1, 15}, 0}], 
     Scaled[{0, 1}, {{2010, 1, 15}, 0}]
     }]}]
```

This incorporates `Scaled`, acknowledging J.M.'s additional comments below as well.

[image: datelist plot]

---

**Edit:** To add multiple such lines to a graph,  the following function takes the dates as arguments and displays them accordingly:

```
specialdates[dates__] := DateListPlot[
  RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All,
  Prolog -> {Directive[Orange], Line[
    {Scaled[{0, -1}, {DateString[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], 0}],
     Scaled[{0, 1}, {DateString[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], 0}]}]
    & /@ {dates}}]
```

So that

```
specialdates["05.11.2005", "04.07.2007", "14.07.2011", "12.10.2017"]
```

yields

[image: multiple dates]

Comment: It might be more useful to use `Scaled[]` for offsetting in the vertical direction. If you use `Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Magenta], Line[{Scaled[{0, -1}, {{2010, 1, 15}, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {{2010, 1, 15}, 0}]}]}`, you'll find that even if you change the `PlotRange`, the vertical magenta line will always hit the horizontal boundaries.

Comment: @J.M. Good plan; I haven't learnt about `Scaled` yet. (It's the scaling/offset/positioning stuff in Mathematica that still confuses me...)

Comment: Here, the notation is not too hard to parse. `Scaled[{0, h}, start]` corresponds to a scaled vertical offset from the point `start`; positive values of `h` go up, and negative values of `h` go down. `h == -1` is the bottommost position, and `h == 1` is the topmost. The situation is similar for horizontal offsetting, with `Scaled[{h, 0}, start]`.

Comment: Ok, the combination of `Epilog` and `Scaled` indeed seems to be the most reasonable solution. Thank you all!

Comment: @Bernd Actually it should probably be `Prolog` instead of `Epilog`

Comment: @Ajasja, good point. I suppose it depends on whether you want the distinguishing markers to go over or under the plot.

Comment: In case anyone, like me, needs to repeatedly apply multiple such lines to graphs, this function takes the dates as arguments and displays them accordingly (unfortunately I can't insert images or proper code rendering in the comments): `specialdates[dates__] := 
 DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Prolog -> {Directive[Orange], 
    Line[{Scaled[{0, -1}, {DateString[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], 
          0}], Scaled[{0, 
          2}, {DateString[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], 
          0}]}] & /@ {dates}}]`

Comment: Usage: `specialdates["05.11.2005", "04.07.2007", "14.07.2011", "12.10.2017"]`

Comment: @bernd feel free to edit this answer or the question with this information. Not sure which would be best, but probably better than in a comment...!

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the multi-date version, @cormullion

Comment: @Bernd, no need for excess; `Scaled[{0, 1}, {DateString[{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], 0}]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking:

> Is there a simple option to add additional grid lines to the automatic ones? Thank you!

Well, I couldn't think of one, but out of curiosity I tried another approach (different to the `Epilog` I'd also rather choose). It seems to work pretty ok, so I figured I might share. As the other answer is much more versatile, I didn't spend too much time tidying up my code, if you are interested in more details let me know.

Consider the `DateListPlot` you mentioned:

```
dlp = DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True, 
      GridLines -> {Automatic, None}];
```

Now, the idea is to just add the desired additional gridlines to `dlp` directly. Using `dlp//FullForm` we can easily identify the `GridLines` and can thus set up the following `ReplacemeAll`:

```
addVertGridLine[plot_,dates_List] := 
   (plot /. 
    # -> 
       Insert[#, 
        Unevaluated[
        Sequence @@ ({AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ dates)], {2,1,-1}]) &@
    Cases[plot, x_Rule /; x[[1]] == GridLines, Infinity][[1]]
```

in words: I use `Cases` to find the `GridLines` and then I insert the (unevaluated) `Sequence` of `dates` in that list, at the right spot (using `AbsoluteTime` to make it a bit more user friendly). The setup expects the user to enter a **list** of date/style lists (in order to make it possible to add many gridlines in one go).

An example will certainly help:

We start with an initial plot:

```
dlp = DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 20], {2000}, Joined -> True, GridLines -> {Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

and let's add few Guy Fawkes days:

```
addVertGridLine[dlp, 
   {{"5 Nov 2005", Directive[Red, Thick]},
    {"5 Nov 2008", GrayLevel[0.8`]}
    {"5 Nov 2012", Directive[Blue, Dashed]}, 
    {"5 Nov 2014", Green}}]
```

showing various formatting.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks ``

If we could identify how the automatic `GridLines` are determined it would be straightforward  ***to add the custom grid lines to the automatic ones***. It seems that we can replicate the automatically generated major date ticks and hence associated grid lines using the function `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` in version 11 (and `` Graphics`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks `` in version 9).

This function takes two arguments with a third optional argument:

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[arg1: {mindate, maxdate}, ndivisons, labelformat]
```

and returns a list of (no more than *ndivisions*)  *"nice"* date divisions in the range from *mindate* to *maxdate* with each tick labeled based on *labelformat*.

For example,

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{{2010, 1}, {2011, 3}}, 5]
```

> {{3.47129*10^9, "Jan"}, {3.47907*10^9, "Apr"}, {3.48693*10^9, 
>           "Jul"}, {3.49488*10^9, "Oct"}, {3.50283*10^9, 
>         "Jan"}, {3.5106*10^9, "Apr"}}

The optional third argument allows formatting of date labels:

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{{2000}, {2018}}, 5, {"Year", "/", "Month"}]
```

> {{3.15567*10^9, "2000/01"}, {3.31353*10^9, "2005/01"}, {3.47129*10^9,
>      "2010/01"}, {3.62906*10^9, "2015/01"}, {3.78683*10^9, "2020/01"}}

The first column of the output gives the automatic grid lines on the date axis. We can append to this list additional grid lines as desired. We can replicate the major ticks on the date axis using the function

```
System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{##}, 5, "Year"]&
```

in the option setting for `FrameTicks` or `Ticks`.

**Examples:**

```
DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 52], {2000}, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> {(Join[System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, 5, "Year"][[All, 1]], 
 {{AbsoluteTime["5 Nov 2007"], Directive[Red, Thick]},
  {AbsoluteTime["5 Mar 2022"], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.007], DotDashed]}}] &), None}]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 60], {2000, 1}, Joined -> True, 
 GridLines -> {(Join[System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, 5, "Year"][[All, 1]], 
 {{AbsoluteTime["5 Nov 2001"], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
  {AbsoluteTime["5 Mar 2003"], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.007], DotDashed]}}] &), None}]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[MeanFilter[RandomReal[1, 500], 50], {2001, 5, 1}, 
 Joined -> True, GridLinesStyle -> Green, 
 GridLines -> {(Join[System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[{#, #2}, 5, "Month"][[All, 1]], 
   {{AbsoluteTime["5 Nov 2001"], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
    {AbsoluteTime["5 Mar 2002"], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.007], DotDashed]}}] &), None}]
```

[image]

### Post-process

Alternatively, extract the grid lines from `DateListPlot` output with automatic `GridLines` and use the modified list of grid lines in `Show`.

```
dlp = DateListPlot[RandomReal[1, 60], {2000, 1}, Joined -> True, 
  GridLines -> {Automatic, None}];
newlines = {{AbsoluteTime["5 Nov 2001"], Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
  {AbsoluteTime["5 Mar 2003"], Directive[Blue, Thickness[.007], DotDashed]}};
Show[dlp, GridLines -> {Join[First[GridLines /. dlp[[2]]], newlines], 
   Last[GridLines /. dlp[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using internal functions and instead use [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions) to obtain the [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines) that are used by default, and then augment them as desired. To do this you will probably need to use the workaround presented in my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138048/45431) to question [(68937)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/45431). Then:

```
plot = DateListPlot[
    RandomReal[1,20],
    {2000},
    GridLines->{Automatic,None},
    Joined->True
];

gridlines = OptionValue[
    AbsoluteOptions @ plot,
    GridLines
]
```

> {{{3.15567*10^9, {GrayLevel[0.], 
>       AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, {3.31353*10^9, {GrayLevel[0.], 
>       AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, {3.47129*10^9, {GrayLevel[0.], 
>       AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, {3.62906*10^9, {GrayLevel[0.], 
>       AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, {3.78683*10^9, {GrayLevel[0.], 
>       AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}}, {}}

Adding more grid lines can be then be done with:

```
newgridlines = Replace[
    gridlines,
    {a_, b_} :> {Join[a, {{AbsoluteTime@"Nov 5 2007", Red}}], b}
];

Show[
    plot,
    GridLines -> newgridlines
]
```

[image]