# More Ticks::ticks errors in AbsoluteOptions in v10

Tags: graphics, functions, bugs, options, ticks

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier, fixed in 13.0.**

---

While the specific bug affecting `Plot` described in [AbsoluteOptions prints error messages in V10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54431/121) has been fixed in 10.0.2 there remain problems with [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html).  The first one I note is failure in resolving function-based [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) as used by `LogPlot`:

```
LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, Frame -> True] // AbsoluteOptions
```

[image]

In the full output the `FrameTicks` option appears as:

```
FrameTicks -> {{}, {}, {}, {}}
```

More errors are seen here:

```
ReliefPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]] // AbsoluteOptions
```

[image]

This despite the fact that the plot has no ticks.  `Automatic` also fails, e.g.:

```
ParametricPlot[r t, {r, 0, 5}, {t, 1, 2}] // AbsoluteOptions
```

[image]

---

Oleksandr notes in the comments that a similar problem has affected versions 7, 8, and 9 as well, though the issued messages are a bit different.  I am therefore updating the header to introduced in 7.0 or earlier.

Comment: The error for `Plot` has not really been fixed. As adding `PlotTheme->"Scientific"` quickly shows. So maybe these problems should be treated as one single problem?

Comment: @gwr That options introduces a frame which seems to be the source of the current problem.  I thought a new question was appropriate to indicate that there are two separate though closely related issues.  **Community: should I edit this question into the one linked at the top (and delete this copy) or keep it as separate?**

Comment: True, but the error is also shown for the Option Axes. Isn't that something different?

Comment: @gwr That's my point. (I think?)  The `Axes::axes` bug appears to have been fixed, along with the one affecting the `Ticks` option.  However a bug with `FrameTicks` remains which I am illustrating here.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your Point: `PlotStyle -> "Web"` does not put up a frame yet still (!) shows `Axes::axes` and `Ticks::ticks` bug at the same time. So what has been "fixed" ?

Comment: @gwr I get no error messages from this code in 10.0.2 under Windows: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> "Web"] // AbsoluteOptions` -- what OS are you running?

Comment: I am running 10.0.2 on Windows 7 (64 Bit).

Comment: @gwr Do you get error messages from that exact code?

Comment: Yes, with a fresh notebook and that exact code I do get (among other errors): `Axes::axes: "{{True,False},{True,False}} is not a valid axis specification. "`

Comment: @gwr Very strange!  I am also running 10.0.2 under Windows 7, 64-bit, and in a fresh kernel I get no errors.  I wonder if something went wrong during your update?  Perhaps some library file was in use and could not be overwritten?

Comment: @gwr I asked in chat for other users to try that code.  I shall report the result, or you can go there to see for yourself.

Comment: Well, how to be sure, but I had booted Windows freshly, closed all programs, checked MD5 and then the old Version 10.0.1 was removed before the new one got installed. Strange...

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` is such a useful tool it is a shame that it has been error/bug ridden for so many versions.

Comment: @gwr I don't see any replies to my query in Chat so I still don't know which of the behaviors we are observing is exceptional.  I shall leave this question as is until I know more.

Comment: I had missed this question until today. Let me just note that the same thing is seen in version 9.0.1, 8.0.4, 7.0.1 in the slightly different form of `Ticks::ticks : <valid explicit tick specification> is not a valid tick specification.` It is correct in 5.2. You are probably right in thinking that `AbsoluteOptions` has been abandoned.

Comment: @Oleksandr Thanks for the report: in supports my suspicion that `FullGraphics` and `AbsoluteOptions` have never been (properly) updated for version 6+ graphics.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "FullGraphics and AbsoluteOptions have never been (properly) updated for version 6+ graphics" Maybe you can post a self-answered question or something for this fact so the several related questions (for example [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97317/1871)) can be properly marked as duplicates?

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm so heartbroken to see this bug persisting in v11

Comment: @QuantumDot I have mostly given up hope on AbsoluteOptions.  The fundamental problem with it is that these things are computed by the front end with information about things like screen resolution, font size, and other things that affect what fits on the screen.  `AbsoluteOptions` has always just given an approximation. So I see the difficulties.  But I am also disappointed that there seems to be no effort to deal with them.

Comment: @QuantumDot Szabolcs kindly went through my list of bugs and updated their status.  Not a single one has been marked fixed.  I continue to be disappointed in the direction this software is heading.  I had genuinely hoped that after the expansion of functions in version 10 that the next release would finally focus on improving the functions that already exist and strengthening the core language, perhaps with better pattern matching etc.  I kind of feel foolish for keeping that hope now as it seems its going to be more of the same.

Comment: Apparently Wolfram prides himself with quantity over quality.  Here is an excerpt from his blog: "there are 555 completely new functions that we’re adding in Version 11—representing a huge amount of new functionality (by comparison, Version 1 had a total of 551 functions altogether)..."  It includes (in my view) trash functions like `ReIm` and `PerfectNumber`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I believe the situation to be. [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) uses `FullAxes` under the hood. It turns out that `FullAxes` is still expecting [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html)/[`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) options to be specified using the old `Frame -> {b, l, t, r}` syntax instead of the new `Frame->{{l, r}, {b, t}}` syntax. This is why `FullAxes` issues messages and doesn't work. This means the solution is simply to fix these options before running [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html)/`FullAxes` on the graphic.

*(update to fix PlotRange as well)*

It turns out that the function PlotRange also has an issue with some "malformed" plot ranges, so I updated the code to handle that as well.

Here is the revised code:

```
Begin["FullAxesDump`"];

With[{graphic = ListLogPlot[{10, 100}]},
    If[Quiet @ TrueQ @ Check[FullAxes @ graphic, True],
        Unprotect[FullAxes];
        FullAxes[arg_] /; !TrueQ@$FACheck := Block[{$FACheck=True},
            FullAxes[fixOptions@arg]
        ];
        Protect[FullAxes];
    ]
]

With[{graphic = Graphics[{}, GridLines->None, PlotRange->{{0, 1}, {All, All}}]},
    If[Quiet @ TrueQ @ Check[PlotRange[graphic], True],
        Unprotect[PlotRange];
        PlotRange[arg_] /; !TrueQ@$FACheck := Block[{$FACheck=True},
            PlotRange[fixOptions[arg]]
        ];
        Protect[PlotRange];
    ]
]

fixOptions[x_]:=x
fixOptions[(tag:Graphics3D|Graphics)[g_,opts__]] := tag[
    g,
    Sequence@@ReplaceAll[
        {opts},
        Rule[h:Frame|FrameTicks|PlotRange,rhs_] :> h->fixRule[h,rhs]
    ],
    Frame->False, Axes->False
]

fixRule[Frame|FrameTicks, {{l_,r_},{b_,t_}}] := {b,l,t,r}
fixRule[Frame|FrameTicks, {d_,s_}] := {d,Automatic,s,Automatic}

fixRule[PlotRange, a_List] := Replace[a, {All, All}->All, {1}]

fixRule[_,rhs_]:=rhs

End[];
```

Some comments:

1. I initally used `` System`Private`NewContextPath `` and `` System`Private`RestoreContextPath ``because I had trouble with contexts of my variable names, but that must have been a transient thing related to earlier code.
2. I only redefine [`FullAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullAxes.html) if using [`FullAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullAxes.html) on a [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) issues messages. This means that if you want to change the code after running it, you will need to first clear the new [`FullAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullAxes.html) downvalue that is created by the code. Something along the lines of `Unprotect[FullAxes]; Clear[FullAxes]; Protect[FullAxes];`
3. I use the `foo /; ! TrueQ@flag := Block[{flag = True}, foo]` trick so that the options get tweaked, and then the existing kernel code for foo gets run.
4. It turns out that `Frame -> False` needs to get explicitly added to the options so that [`FullAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullAxes.html) realizes that there really isn't a [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html), and it must process the [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)/[`Axes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Axes.html) code. Without `Frame -> False`, the [`FullAxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullAxes.html) code turns `Axes -> True` into `Axes -> {False, False}`. Note that options handling uses the first instance of an option, so adding the default (`Frame -> False`) at the end should not affect output.

I think that's enough explanation. Here is what happens after loading the above code:

```
AbsoluteOptions[LogPlot[x^x, {x, 1, 5}, Frame -> True], FrameTicks];

AbsoluteOptions[ReliefPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}]]];

AbsoluteOptions[ParametricPlot[r t, {r, 0, 5}, {t, 1, 2}]];
```

No error messages, although I don't claim that this fixes all cases where [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) issues messages. A similar treatment is possible for [`FullGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullGraphics.html)

Comment: In my system (version 11.0.0) `fixOptions // Definition` returns `Null` and ``FullAxesDump`fixOptions // Definition`` returns the definition even without ``System`Private`NewContextPath``.

Comment: @AlexyPopkov Not sure why I had an issue, then. I should have tried quitting my kernel first to see if that fixed my context switching issue. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you perhaps be willing to tackle a related question of mine? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/121  This one appears to be a sub-part of it.  And the overarching question remains as to the long term intent for this function.

Comment: Change FullAxes to FullGraphics, and add FrameLabel.