# AbsoluteOptions doesn't return correct option value of Ticks

Tags: plotting, options

**This has been fixed in version 13.0.**

Also seems to work with explicit `Automatic`, `None`, `All` etc. statements.

---

I just come across a function called [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) when trying to figure out the specific option value of `Ticks -> Automatic` in `Plot`, which, as said in its document, will give "the actual settings for options used internally by the Wolfram Language when the setting given is `Automatic` or `All`", but it seems not to work properly. Consider the following example:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]
option = First@AbsoluteOptions[p1, Ticks];
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, Evaluate@option]
```

[image]
[image]

Apparently `p1` and `p2` are different, what have I missed?

If `AbsoluteOptions` just doesn't work, how can I find the specific value of default setting of `Ticks`?

I'm still using v9.0.1.

Comment: Yep, long standing problem.  `AbsoluteOptions` is just a rough approximation.  I believe that might be because `AbsoluteOptions` is implemented within the kernel while the automatic graphics features are really computed by the front end, based on things such as the size of text based on available fonts, etc. that the kernel has no access to.  But I might be wrong.

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions` for graphics and `FullGraphics` last worked properly in version 5. Perhaps you should report it as a bug, although I'm sure many people have done already in the 8 years since version 6 was released. I don't hold out much hope that these will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Searching for those two functions here should give you a list of questions about problems that are effectively the same as yours. It really is annoying that these two have been seemingly abandoned.

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, actually I already noticed [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10#comment226296_68937) before posting the question, but still decided to cry out loud :)

Comment: @MarcoB Well, I'm afraid it's just a related one, at most. I'm still in v9.0.1 :)

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I realized that. As I understand it, however, I'm afraid that this community will not be able to answer your question meaningfully since it seems that the function has been more or less abandoned, so  I took your opportunity to make the connection the fact that the same annoying problem persists even in more recent versions of *Mathematica*. (+1)

Comment: I'm frustrated about `AbsoluteOptions`, too - but have to agree with @MarcoB that this appears to be a dead horse (or perhaps a deceased parrot).

Comment: @marcob After a second (perhaps I should say third?)  thought, I think marking this question as a duplicate of the linked post isn't proper. That post just points out `AbsoluteOptions` is buggy, but doesn't give any workaround, for which I've asked in my question. Indeed, I thought there doesn't exist a simple workaround, until I read [this amazing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132573/1871) recently :D . Let's reopen this post and post that workaround as an answer!

Comment: @xzczd The post has been reopened for a while. Would you please add a self-answer referencing or expanding on the one you liked? I wouldn't want this post to be reopened for nothing.

Comment: @MarcoB Well, actually I've [invited Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132568/extract-ticks-from-plot/132573#comment420196_132573) to post an answer, but he doesn't reply so far…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, seems that [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) is busy these years, so let me answer the question myself.

In *v13.0* `AbsoluteOptions` is finally updated, and the problem in the question no longer exists:

[image]

If you're in earlier versions, then the undocumented function mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132573/1871) can be used to circumvent the problem:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]

ticks = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@@ PlotRange@p1;

p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image]

Oops… the style of `1.` is still undesired, but this seems to be a bug in *v9.0.1*, and doesn't exist at least in *v12.3.1*.

Comment: It doesn't work with LogPlot. Do you know why? My MMA is 13.1

Comment: @LEO Looks like a bug. I suggest reporting it to WRI. It's not hard to fix, though: `p1 = LogPlot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]; option = First@AbsoluteOptions[p1, Ticks] /. a_FormBox :> ToExpression@a; Plot[Sin[x] // Log, {x, 0, 4}, Evaluate@option, PlotRange -> {-3.5, 0}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -3.5}]`