# Extract ticks from plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am trying to extract the ticks settings of a plot to re-design the plot in a custom plot function (effectively, giving the plot a custom design but automatically). I think the ticks should be accessible using `AbsoluteOptions`. However, in this example:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}]
xticks = First[Ticks /. First[AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]]]
```

the major ticks on the x-axis of the plot are at 0,5,10,15,20. `xticks`, on the contrary, looks like:

```
{
 {0., 0., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {2.5, 2.5, {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {5., 5., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {7.5, 7.5, {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {10., 10., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {12.5, 12.5, {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {15., 15., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {17.5, 17.5, {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {20., 20., {0.00625, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}},
 {0.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {1., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {1.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {2., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {3., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {3.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {4., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {4.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {5.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {6., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {6.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {7., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {8., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {8.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {9., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {9.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {10.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {11., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {11.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {12., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {13., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {13.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {14., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {14.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {15.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {16., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {16.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {17., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {18., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {18.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], 
   AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {19., "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}},
 {19.5, "", {0.00375, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.125]}}
}
```

I believe the rows with an entry in the second column should be the major ticks, where the second column is the label. But in the plot there are no ticks at 2.5, 7.5, and so on (neither major nor minor ticks). So why are those listed in the AbsoluteOptions of the plot? Or is there another proper way to extract the actually displayed ticks?

Comment: The ticks don't match with `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, Evaluate@AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]]`.

Comment: I think `AbsoluteOptions` is [deprecated](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10). You can try the [CustomTicks package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/).

Comment: I am actually using CustomTicks to re-design the plot in my custom plot function. The entire purpose of the function is to take charge of all the design aspects of the plot without having to define so many options in the original plot command. So far, I extract the plot range from the ugly default plot and feed it to CustomTicks. The problem is that the tick spacing is too tight. CustomTicks with automatic spacing draws major ticks every 2.5 in the above example. I want to use the automatically rendered separation of 5.

Comment: This behavior is only for `Automatic` settings, if you manually specify ticks and then read them through `AbsoluteOptions` you get the actual value. Try `plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 20, 5], Range[-1, 1, .5]}]`

Comment: That's good to know. However, I am most interested in using the automatically generated ticks in my custom plot function. Somehow, this information must be stored in the plot object, mustn't it?

Comment: It seems like what is stored is not working for even some _Mathematica_ functions. Read [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/44141) about how `FullGraphics` complains about default settings.

Comment: I wonder if they determine it at render time if the settings are `Automatic`

Comment: But it's not that `AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]` would return something like "Automatic". How can it even distinguish, if I draw the same plot later, the output from manually added ticks at a spacing of 2.5? For instance, if I define the output of Karsten's comment by `plot2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, Evaluate@AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]]`. If I then read `AbsoluteOptions[plot2, Ticks]` it is the same as the output of `AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]`, but printing `plot` and `plot2` results in different ticks.

Comment: That's easy. You can do `Cases[plot, Rule[Ticks, t_] :> t, Infinity]` to see if they are `Automatic` or not. Compare running on `plot` vs. `plot2`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try to build the automatic ticks manually using the undocumented internal function `` Charting`FindTicks ``.

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}];

Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@ PlotRange[plot][[1]]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0}, {5., 5}, {10., 10}, {15., 15}, {20., 20},
>  {0., "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},
>  {1., "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}},
>  {2., "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, 
>  .
>  .
>  .
> }
> ```

Note that `PlotRange[plot]` returns the plot range, also undocumented.

Comment: Phenomenal! Since the function is undocumented, could you elaborate what the arguments are for? I mean the `[{0, 1}, {0, 1}]` after `FindTicks`. Also, how is it possible to find undocumented functions?

Comment: Also, `PlotRange` seems to fail if certain features are present in the plot. For instance, if the plot has a legend, it fails: `plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> "a"];PlotRange[plot]` fails with `PlotRange::gtype: Legended is not a type of graphics.`

Comment: @Felix Re: finding undocumented functions see [(805)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121) and links within; [(1742)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121) is very useful as well.  You can use ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions @ Charting`FindTicks`` to look at the definition of this function yourself to check on what happens to `{0, 1}` in my example.  These appear to be parameters to work with scaling functions as they are used to create `Rescale`-based functions used internally.

Comment: @Felix The case with a legend is not actually a failure, just a limitation.  As the error message informs you `plot` in this case *is not* a `Graphics` expression but has the Head `Legended`.  `PlotRange @ First @ plot` will work.  If you need to preserve the legend you will need to keep its other parameter to reconstruct a new `Legended` expression.  For example you could write: ``{plot, legend} = List @@ Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> "a"]`` and then later `Legended[plot, legend]`.  Also see `MapAt`.

Comment: I think you can post an answer here?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97317/1871

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comment of @grbl , there is indeed a workaround to get automatic plot ticks that can be read out using `AbsoluteOptions` by using `CustomTicks`. It requires very little extra coding:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 20}, Ticks -> LinTicks]
xticks = First[Ticks /. First[AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks]]]
(*
{{0., " 0", {0.04, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {5., 
  " 5", {0.04, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {10., 
  "10", {0.04, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {15., 
  "15", {0.04, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {20., 
  "20", {0.04, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {1., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {2., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {3., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {4., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {6., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {7., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {8., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {9., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {11., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {12., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {13., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {14., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {16., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {17., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {18., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}, {19., 
  "", {0.015, 0.}, {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[2.]}}}
*)
```