# How to add ticks without losing the default ones?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am trying to add some ticks but I would like the default ticks on the $x$-axis to keep appearing. If I use the following they vanish:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}, Ticks -> {{Pi, 2}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}]
```

based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132573/22013):

```
ticks = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@ PlotRange[plot][[1]];
newticks = {{Pi, Pi}}~Join~ticks;
Show[plot, Ticks -> {newticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: could you edit it including new ticks also along the y-axis, such as Pi?

Comment: @AndreaG That's easy and you can do it yourself: change `[[1]]` to `[[2]]`, make some `newticks2` like in the answer, and do `Ticks -> {newticks, newticks2}`.

Comment: what if I wanted only those new ticks to be red?

Comment: Replace `{Pi, Pi}` with `{Pi, Style[Pi, Red]}`.

Comment: in this case it seems to me that only the text Pi gets red, but not the tick. Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: I am also trying to extend it to the case where the plot is LogLogPlot...