# AxesOrigin doesn't appear in plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have:

```
Show[Plot[1/(2 Pi x^2), {x, 0.26, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.26, 1}, {0, 4}}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 0.26, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.26, 1}, {0, 4}}], 
LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0.26, 0}]
```

[image]

Why the origin $0.26$ (on the horizontal axis) doesn't appear in plot? ($0$ in the vertical axis is fine.)

**EDIT**

In the case where the origin is $(0.2, 0)$, the plot is fine:

```
Show[Plot[1/(2 Pi x^2), {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.2, 1}, {0, 4}}], Plot[1 - x, {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.2, 1}, {0, 4}}], 
LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0.2, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: It does if you do e.g. `Show[Plot[1/(2 Pi x^2), {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.2, 1}, {0, 4}}],
  Plot[1 - x, {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.2, 1}, {0, 4}}],  
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0.26, 0}, 
 Axes -> True]` https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eUbG.png

Comment: If I understand you correctly, may be you should rephrase your question: the axis appears but not the label (?)

Comment: I assume the OP wants a _tick_ at $0.26$. You can add it manually as shown [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145382/75628).

Comment: Ticks appear on axes. If a `Frame` is enabled, `FrameTicks` appear as specified. `AxesOrigin` simply determines the origin. You can study this solution further:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIidi.png

Comment: You will have to let go of the Tick at 0.3 or else it will overlap and look non-professional.  Also specify, if you want to see 0 for the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ticks >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html)

[image]

As a work-around, you can use `Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}` to get bottom and left axes. Then, prepend your desired tick to the list of ticks generated by `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {8, 8}] & `` and use it for the horizontal ticks specification in option `FrameTicks`:

```
Show[Plot[1/(2 Pi x^2), {x, 0.26, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.26, 1}, {0, 4}}], 
 Plot[1 - x, {x, 0.26, 1}], 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0.26, 0},  
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None},
    {Prepend[{.26, .26, {.01, 0}}] @ 
       Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {8, 8}] &, None}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
Join[{{.26, .26, {.01, 0}}}, Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {8, 8}]] &
```

to specify the horizontal ticks.

Comment: @Nima, remove the option `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Show[Plot[1/(2 Pi x^2), {x, 0.26, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.26, 1}, {0, 4}}, 
  Ticks -> {{0.26, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}, Automatic}], 
 Plot[1 - x, {x, 0.26, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.26, 1}, {0, 4}}], 
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0.26, 0}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I am not sure that you are using acceptable wording.

Comment: The option `Ticks` overrides the previous settings and instructs Mathematica to only use those ticks one specifies in this option. Therefore, if one needs any special form of ticks he should specify them in all details. The ways to do it you can find in the answer of @kgrl. Besides, have a look as Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Ticks