# Choosing desired text on the axis

Tags: plotting

I've got this plot for instance.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True]
```

how can I insert a text on the axis, for exapmple between 1 and 2 I want to write "a"

like this:

[image]

This is the new problem:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [145368](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145368/how-to-add-ticks-without-losing-the-default-ones).

Comment: thanks. couldn't use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another possibility

```
p = Plot[x, {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> 20, 
  Epilog -> Style[Text["Tid", {1.5, -.35}, {0, 1}], Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks very much. it works well. problem solved

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks ->
  {{Automatic, None}, {{1, {1.5, "a"}, 2, 3, 4, 5}, None}}]
```

[image]

With some styling options:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 5},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks ->
  {{Automatic, None}, {{1, {1.5, Style["a", Bold, Blue, 14]}, 2, 3, 4, 5}, None}},
 GridLines -> {Range[5], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that with this method, the minor ticks on the axes are now lost.

Comment: Good observation - I didn't notice that

Comment: thanks very much.