# Drop some of the Automatic ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, ticks

Is there a way to drop some of the ticks automatically produced by Mathematica in a 3D plot? I would like to drop, say, the first one of the z-axis since it overlaps with the last one of the y-axis.

Comment: An illustrative example would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `` Charting`FindTicks `` to generate ticks automatically and then remove the ones you don't want. That's more or less the same as taking the default ticks and removing some of those.

I learned about `` Charting`FindTicks `` from Mr. Wizard's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132573/731).

Start with a basic plot:

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use `` Charting`FindTicks `` to generate ticks for it:

```
{xticks, yticks, zticks} = Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@@ PlotRange[plot];
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Ticks -> {xticks, yticks, zticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It didn't generate exactly the same ticks as the default ticks function, but it's close. If you inspect e.g. `xticks` now, you'll see a list of major and minor ticks:

```
{{-3., -3}, {-2., -2}, {-1., -1}, {0., 0}, {1., 1}, {2., 2}, {3., 
  3}, {-3., "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, {-2.8, 
  "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, {-2.6, 
  "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, {-2.4, 
  "", {0.005, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}, ...
```

You can now remove ticks you don't want. Let's say that you don't want the -3 and 3, then you can do this:

```
xticks = xticks /. {{-3., -3} -> Nothing, {3., 3} -> Nothing};
```

Let's confirm that they're gone:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Ticks -> {xticks, yticks, zticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As expected, the -3 and 3 ticks are no longer there.