# How to show decimal points on the axes frames in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a set of data g1  and when plot using n1, i got the plot shown in figure below. I need to change the x-axis label from (1,2,3,4,5...) to (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0) and y-axis label from  (50000,100000,150000,200000..) to 5.0*10^4,1.0*10^5,1.5*10^5.....).

```
ClearAll[g1, n1]
g1 = {{0.82, 234946}, {0.98, 161961}, {1.54, 66395}, {1.64, 57980}, {1.76, 
50441}, {1.95, 41107}, {2.06, 36881}, {2.24, 30890}, {2.47, 25453}, {2.74, 
20549}, {3.09, 16209}, {4.59, 8286}, {4.94, 8049}, {5.26, 8651}, {5.62, 
12012}, {5.83, 20244}, {5.97, 43136}, {6.03, 90541}, {6.18, -2.29*10^-11 - 
124787*I}, {6.51, -8.099*10^-13 - 4408*I}, {6.87,-1.47*10^-13 - 803*I}};
n1 = ListLinePlot[g1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, Axes -> True,FrameLabel -> 
{{"kx",None}, {"Photon energy (eV)",None}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, 
{-30000,250000}}, Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

[image]

---

I tried to solve it based on the below code suggested by some friends here but still not able to get what i wants. The code i wrote are as below

```
ClearAll[g1, n1]
g1 = {{0.82, 234946}, {0.98, 161961}, {1.54, 66395}, {1.64, 57980}, {1.76, 
50441}, {1.95, 41107}, {2.06, 36881}, {2.24, 30890}, {2.47, 25453}, {2.74, 
20549}, {3.09, 16209}, {4.59, 8286}, {4.94, 8049}, {5.26, 8651}, {5.62, 
12012}, {5.83, 20244}, {5.97, 43136}, {6.03, 90541}, {6.18, -2.29*10^-11 - 
124787*I}, {6.51, -8.099*10^-13 - 4408*I}, {6.87,-1.47*10^-13 - 803*I}};
fm=FrameTicks/.AbsoluteOptions[n1,FrameTicks]
(fm[[2, #, 2]] = EngineeringForm[fm[[2, #, 2]]]) & /@ Range[6]

(fm[[1, #, 2]] = AccountingForm[fm[[1, #, 2]], {1, 0}, 
                      NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]) & /@ Range[8]
ListLinePlot[g1,PlotStyle->{Blue},
FrameLabel->{{"kx",None},{"Photon energy (eV)",None}},
PlotRange->{{0,7},{-30000,250000}},Frame->True,
LabelStyle->{12,GrayLevel[0]},
FrameTicks->{{fm[[2]],Automatic},{fm[[1]],Automatic}}]
```

Please someone help me for this one.

Comment: Please use the search function before making a new question - You should be able to answer all your questions by looking at other answers on this site. Also, only ask one question be post

Comment: @Mathe172, I am sorry for multiple questions. Now i make it only one question. I searched about showing decimal points on the axes frame but doesn't show anything.

Comment: How about [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks)? That and the documentation of `FrameTicks` should get you started

Comment: @Mathe172, I go through    FrameTicks and tried many ways but couldn't get succeed. If you or anyone knows, please give me the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need to change the x-axis label from (1,2,3,4,5...) to
>   (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0) and y-axis label from
>   (50000,100000,150000,200000..) to 5.0*10^4,1.0*10^5,1.5*10^5.....).

This is something to get you started. First obtain the `FrameTicks` used

```
n1=ListLinePlot[g1,PlotStyle->{Blue},
  Axes->True,
  FrameLabel->{{"kx",None},{"Photon energy (eV)",None}},
  PlotRange->{{0,7},{-30000,250000}},
  Frame->True,
  LabelStyle->{12,GrayLevel[0]}
]
fm=FrameTicks/.AbsoluteOptions[n1,FrameTicks]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now do

```
(*adjust major tick labels on the y axis. You might need to adjust this*)
(* more to get the exact engineering format you wanted *)
(fm[[2, #, 2]] = EngineeringForm[fm[[2, #, 2]]]) & /@ Range[6]

(fm[[1, #, 2]] = AccountingForm[fm[[1, #, 2]], {1, 0}, 
                          NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]) & /@ Range[8]
```

And replot again

```
ListLinePlot[g1,PlotStyle->{Blue},
  FrameLabel->{{"kx",None},{"Photon energy (eV)",None}},
  PlotRange->{{0,7},{-30000,250000}},
  Frame->True,
  LabelStyle->{12,GrayLevel[0]},
  FrameTicks->{{fm[[2]],Automatic},{fm[[1]],Automatic}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use the above, there is known bug in using `AbsoluteOptions[..., FrameTicks]` and that bug is still in 11.3 [more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10)  so I used Answer above by Carl Woll and loaded the code shown there to fix the bug, so that the above code will work. So you need to load the code in the above link first for this to work.

Comment: Hi Naseer, I copy your code above but it gives different than yours     fm = FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[n1, FrameTicks];
(fm[[1, #, 2]] = 
     AccountingForm[fm[[1, #, 2]], {1, 0}, 
      NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}]) & /@ Range[8];
(fm[[2, #, 2]] = EngineeringForm[fm[[2, #, 2]]]) & /@ Range[6];
ListLinePlot[g1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"kx", None}, {"Photon energy (eV)", None}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-30000, 250000}}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{fm[[2]], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}].  Where did i goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I now understand to get the decimal places along the axis. For that, it requires  slight changes in the FrameTicks as shown below.

```
ListLinePlot[g1,PlotStyle->{Blue},FrameLabel->{{"kx",None},{"Photon energy 
(eV)",None}},PlotRange->{{0,7},{-30000,250000}},Frame->True,LabelStyle-> 
{12,GrayLevel[0]},FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,Automatic}, {Transpose[{#, 
Map[PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] &, #]}] &[Range[0, 7, 1.0]], Automatic}}]
```

Still no idea about the y-axis labeling in scientific notations.

Answer (score 0):

This is closest I can get.

```
    xTick = Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] &, #]}] &[
   Range[0, 7, 1.0]];

yTick = {{0, PaddedForm[0., {2, 1}]}, {50 10^3, 
    PaddedForm[5., {2, 1}] Superscript[10, 4]}, {10 10^4, 
    PaddedForm[1., {2, 1}] Superscript[10, 5]}, {15 10^4, 
    PaddedForm[1.5, {2, 1}] Superscript[10, 5]}, {20 10^4, 
    PaddedForm[2., {2, 1}] Superscript[10, 5]}, {25 10^4, 
    PaddedForm[2.5, {2, 1}] Superscript[10, 5]}};

ListLinePlot[g1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"kx", None}, {"Photon energy 
    (eV)", None}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-30000, 250000}}, 
 Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yTick, 
    Automatic}, {Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] &, #]}] &[
     Range[0, 7, 1.0]], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Here is what you want

```
xTick = Transpose[{Range[0, 7], {Style["0.0"], Style["1.0"], 
     Style["2.0"], Style["3.0"], Style["4.0"], Style["5.0"], 
     Style["6.0"], Style["7.0"]}}];

yTick = {{0, Style["0.0"]}, {50 10^3, 
    Style["5.0\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)"]}, {10 \
10^4, Style[
     "1.0\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)"]}, {15 10^4, 
    Style["1.5\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)"]}, {20 \
10^4, Style[
     "2.0\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)"]}, {25 10^4, 
    Style["2.5\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)"]}};

ListLinePlot[g1, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"kx", None}, {"Photon energy 
    (eV)", None}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-30000, 250000}}, 
 Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> {12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{yTick, 
    Automatic}, {Transpose[{#, Map[PaddedForm[#, {2, 1}] &, #]}] &[
     Range[0, 7, 1.0]], Automatic}}]
```

[image]