# Returning properties of plot

Tags: plotting

How can I find out the DefaultStyle of Axes, Frames, PlotRangeClipping of Plot, DensityPlot, etc. and can I manipulate them?

Comment: `Options@Plot`, and `SetOptions`?

Answer (score 1):

Default styles for `Axes`, `Ticks`, `Frame` (`DefaultAxesStyle`, `DefaultTickStyle`, etc.) are options for `GraphicsBox`:

```
defaultstyles = Symbol /@ Names["Default*Style"]
```

[image]

```
graphicsDefaultStyles = DeleteCases[Quiet @ Options[GraphicsBox, defaultstyles], 
  HoldPattern[DefaultBaseStyle -> _]]
```

[image]

These styles are defined in style sheets and can be discovered using `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, stylename}]`:

```
{#, CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #2}]} & @@@ graphicsDefaultStyles // Grid
```

[image]

We can also use `CurrentValue[{GraphicsBoxOptions, ...}]` to get the default styles:

```
CurrentValue[{GraphicsBoxOptions, #}] & /@ defaultstyles
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AbsoluteOptions for  the first part of question.

Comment: It's not a good idea: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/1871

Comment: @xzczd That link doesn't say that there is any wrong about AbsoluteOptions, as far as I can see.

Comment: Don't miss the link there… OK I should have directly post this link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/1871