# can someone how to plot $x = c$ in a different color scheme?

Tags: plotting

Exactly as title says. I do not know why I am having so much trouble with this. I have googled many solutions and I cannot find a straightforward answer.

Also, the only method I know is "Gridlines" and there is no option to change colour

Comment: `PlotStyle`? Do not g**gle, press F1. And about `GridLines`, well, there is an option `GridLinesStyle` too.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3561/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses `GridLines` that are specific colors at specific positions:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 GridLines -> {{{Pi, Blue}, {3 Pi, Orange}}, None}]
```

[image]