# How to add the position of an added vertical line to the plot itself?

Tags: plotting

[In this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot) it is answered how to add a vertical line to a graph. However, it has not been shown that how can someone add the position of that vertical line to the axis.
How can I add the coordinate of a vertical line to the graph itself? I want to be able to change the font size of the coordinate too.
By using the code below I can change the font size of the coordinate of axes. I want similar thing for the solution to this question too.

```
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 80]
```

Here is an example:

```
line3 = Line[{{2.33, -2}, {2.33, 2}}];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle ->Directive[Thick, Bold, 20], Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], line3}]
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code for the `Plot` as well? And where you want your vertical line.

Comment: @Öskå. I added more details.

Comment: `FrameTicks -> {{0, 1, 2.33, 3, 4, 5, 6}, Automatic}`?

Comment: Where should be the position of the vertical line located? I have [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OKZ.png) but it's ugly since everything is so huge.

Comment: @Öskå. The position is not that much important. In this example I placed the vertical line at 2.33.

Comment: I mean where position of the label should be located.. :)

Comment: @Pickett. It does the job. Thank you.

Comment: @Öskå. The position of label? The line is at 2.33 so I expect a number 2.33 below the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to change the ticks (with [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html)) on the axes manually.

```
FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{0, 1, 2.33, 3, 4, 5, 6}, None}}
```

If you have a large number of ticks on your axes writing them down like this could be cumbersome, in which case you could try to generate the range and then replace another tick with the new tick or insert the extra tick that you want, like this:

```
{{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[6] /. 2 -> 2.33, None}}
```

or

```
{{Automatic, Automatic}, {Insert[Range[6], 2.33, 3], None}}
```

Result:

[image: Plot]

---

One can then easily make it automatic (thank you [Öskå](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1356/%c3%96sk%c3%a5) for this code and animation):

```
line3[y_] := Line[{{y, -2}, {y, 2}}];
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Bold, 20], 
    Epilog -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], line3[t]}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[0, 6] /. Round@t -> t, None}}], {t, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: I added a more general case based on your idea, I hope you don't mind. If you do feel free to delete it :)

Comment: @Öskå I think it's great, thank you! :)

Comment: Stop thanking me in public, I'm going to blush ;o) It's just that I was about the post this answer right after you posted yours, so I thought that I would put mine in yours.. :)

Answer (score 4):

An answer with `GridLines`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Bold, 20], 
 GridLines -> {{2.33}, None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
 Epilog -> Text[Framed[2.33], {2.33, -0.9}, Background -> White]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Bold, 20], GridLines -> {{m}, None}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
  Epilog -> 
   Text[Framed[NumberForm[m, 3]], {m, -0.9}, 
    Background -> White]], {m, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]