# Additional tick marks in a LogLogPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks, logarithmic-scale

In the following mwe, I have a loglogplot. I want to display the tick positions where the horizontal and vertical lines meet the axes.

```
f[x_] = 10^(-10)*Log[x];

LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^7}, 
 Epilog -> { 
   Line[{{Log[5*10^6], Log[f[5*10^3]]}, {Log[5*10^6], 
      Log[f[5*10^6]]}}], 
   Line[{{Log[5*10^3], Log[f[5*10^6]]}, {Log[5*10^6], 
      Log[f[5*10^6]]}}]}]
```

[image]

I found [a related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50965/how-to-add-the-position-of-an-added-vertical-line-to-the-plot-itself/50967#50967) post, but the additional ticks there mess up with the other ticks. I want to keep the rest of my major and minor ticks the intact.

Answer (score 3):

```
llp = LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^7}, 
   Prolog -> {Line[{{Log[5*10^6], Log[f[5*10^3]]}, {Log[5*10^6], Log[f[5*10^6]]}}], 
     Line[{{Log[5*10^3], Log[f[5*10^6]]}, {Log[5*10^6], Log[f[5*10^6]]}}]}];
```

Extract the ticks used in `llp` using `AbsoluteOptions`:

```
{tx, ty} = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[llp, Ticks];
```

or generate them using the function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``

```
{tx2, ty2} = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##, {6, 6}] & @@@ PlotRange[llp];
```

Specify the new ticks:

```
newxtick = {N@Log[5*10^6], Style[N@5*10^6, Red], {0.03, 0.01}, 
     {Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]}};

newytick = {N@Log[f[5*10^6]], Style[N@f[5*10^6], Red], {0.03, 0.01}, 
    {Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]}};
```

Add them to the original ticks list:

```
ticks = {DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@Prepend[tx2, newxtick], 
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[First]@Prepend[ty2, newytick]};
```

Use `Show` with the option `Ticks -> ticks`:

```
Show[llp, Ticks -> ticks, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f[x_] = 10^(-10)*Log[x];

Plot[f[x], {x, 10^4, 10^7}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 Ticks -> {{5.*10^4, 5.*10^5, 5.*10^6} /. 
    x_?NumberQ -> {x, ScientificForm[x]}, {1.0*10^-9, 
    1.25*10^-9, {f[5*10^6] // N, 
     NumberForm[f[5*10^6] // N, {2, 1}]}}}, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{Log[5*10^6], Log[f[5*10^3]]}, {Log[5*10^6], 
      Log[f[5*10^6]]}}], 
   Line[{{Log[5*10^3], Log[f[5*10^6]]}, {Log[5*10^6], 
      Log[f[5*10^6]]}}]}]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Yes, but as I said above I cannot afford to change the positions of the original ticks in my plot. I just want the extra ticks at the position of intersection of the lines with the axes. Thanks

Comment: If you read my answer you see how one can include the ticks one needs. Just as I did, you can include those ticks you want and fix for them the format you wish. Have a look at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Ticks/Scope/TicksPositionandLabeling and there example Nr. 5