# How do I add a vertical thick line to log-log plots?

Tags: plotting

How do I add a vertical thick line to my `ListLogLogPlot`? I tried with the following code (a minimal non working example), but I get an error (the plot becomes pink)

```
 tab=Table[{j,j^2},{j,1,1000,10}]
 tab1=Table[{j,j^1/2},{j,1,1000,10}]
 ListLogLogPlot[{tab1, tab}, GridLines -> {{790,Thick}, {1}}]
```

I also tried with `Epilog` as written  in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3561/8822) question: it gives no error, but it doesn't plot any vetical line.

I use Mathematica 10

Comment: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Epilog -> {Thickness[0.03], InfiniteLine[{3, 0}, {0, 1}]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy solution is to add the option `GridLinesStyle`

```
ListLogLogPlot[{tab1, tab}, GridLines -> {{ 790 }, {1}}, 
GridLinesStyle -> { Thick, None} ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For the first one, you're missing a pair of brackets. The format is `{xlist, ylist}` where `xlist` is in the form `{{x1, style}, {x2, style}...}`. A lot of brackets, admittedly.

```
tab = Table[{j, j^2}, {j, 1, 1000, 10}];
tab1 = Table[{j, j^1/2}, {j, 1, 1000, 10}];
ListLogLogPlot[{tab1, tab}, GridLines -> {
   {{790, Thick}},
   {}
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the `Epilog` attempt, I'm guessing that you probably did not take the logarithm of the x value. It should be done like this:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{tab1, tab}, Epilog -> {
   Thick,
   InfiniteLine[{{Log@700, 0}, {Log@700, 1}}]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The labels are placed on a logarithmic scale, but the underlying coordinate system is still linear. That is why we have to take the logarithm of our coordinates to get the expected result when using `ListLogLogPlot`.