# I don't understand the Epilog function

Tags: plotting

I had the same question as [How to add a vertical line to a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot) and I have read the first answer using the Epilog function.

This answer solved my problem and my code is now working.

However, I don't understand why Epilog is needed by mathematica in the code. It is written in the documentation : "Epilog is an option for graphics functions that gives a list of graphics primitives to be rendered after the main part of the graphics is rendered.".

Indeed the code doesn't work without Epilog, it means if we directly put Line in the plot command. But why does Epilog solve this problem ? Why the fact to render the line after the rest of the graphic is rendered would make the thing work.

I don't understand this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal environment for a `Line` instruction to live in would be the `Graphics` function environment.

`Line` is just one example of the many drawing instruction that `Graphics` knows.

The `Plot` function itself is not a `Graphics` environment and knows nothing about drawing functions. The result of a `Plot` statement, however, is a `Graphics` function with all drawing instructions included to create the desired plot.

The effect of the `Epilog` *option* is to pass the drawing instructions in its argument to this `Graphics` environment created by `Plot`. As the name suggests, this is done *after* the plot drawing instructions. There is a similar option called `Prolog` which also insert drawing instructions. However, this option inserts its argument *before* the plot drawing instruction.

Comment: Personally I have always been unconfortable with the term *after* and *before* in a context that has nothing to do with time, though that seems to be a established habit. Here the term *after* means that the graphics from the `Epilog` hides the other ones. (This is only a Note, Don't change your answer for this)

Comment: @andre The use of *before* and *after* with regard to place, position, time, and motion goes back to Old English, and probably earlier.

Comment: @andre You could really think of it as a process in time. The Graphics instructions are processed in order of appearance, which means that Prolog instructions execute *before* the Plot instructions. The Epilog instructions are executed *after* the Plot instructions have been evaluated. But before and after are quite common expressions of spatial localization as any dictionary may attest.